# session_start() not working in xampp

Tags: php, formatted

I created two files 
   1.php 
   2.php 
 which are in the same folder(i am using xampp).
 In 1.php used session_start() and also used $_session['name']=abc. Then i opened 2.php to check whether session was created or not

2.php:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_session['name'])){

  echo $_session['name'];
 }
  else{
  echo "no session found!!";

  }
   ?>
```

and it keeps on saying "no session found!!"

Plz help ...

I searched a few sites n they say that by default d session is for whole folder containing
d script and session_set_cookie_params($lifetime,'/') (where $lifetime=60*60)  is also nt helping.
On d other hand if at d end of1.php i use require("2.php") then abc is displayed.

Comment: have you started session in `2.php` ?

Comment: mention your 1.php code here

Comment: It's `$_SESSION`. Names are case sensitive.

Comment: well changing session to SESSION worked wonders,thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is right in `1.php`,
however, `2.php` must start the session before using it.

2.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
 }
 else{
     echo "no session found!!";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `session_start();` again at the top of every page where you want to access `$_SESSION` variables, not only on the page where you want to initiate the session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
}else{
    echo "no session found!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: The session variable is still ALL UPPERCASE, not lowercase: `$_SESSION` - and this is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `session_start()` at the top of your `2.php` file which is needed to access `$_SESSION` variables.

```
<?php
session_start(); // missing
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
}
else
{
    echo "no session found!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: its also better to include some descriptive sentence along with the code example.